# How to loop to a third level dimensional array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Firstly, I want to loop and display the categories dynamically. It's Parent `Category > Child Category > Inner Child Category`. I was able to loop categories till Child Category only. Tried to loop to the third level(inner child category) but failed miserably.

I was able to loop till the child category however when I tried to access the inner child category. It loops  instance of the inner category to all child category. It should only loop accordingly to it's category not all.

Here is my code. Please do tell me where I did wrong

```
    $taxonomies = array( 
         'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'

    );
    $args = array(
        'number' => 8,
        'parent' => 0,
        'hide_empty' => FALSE,
        'exclude' => array( 16 )
    );

    $parent_product_categories = get_terms($taxonomies,$args);

    $html .= '<div class="sc-tab-wrapper">';    
        $html .= '<ul class="sc-tabs">';
            $datatab = 0;
            foreach($parent_product_categories as $parentprodcat) {
            $datatab++;
            $top_term_id = $parentprodcat->term_id;
            $top_term_name = $parentprodcat->name;
            $top_term_tax = $parentprodcat->taxonomy;

            $html .= '<li id="'.$top_term_id.'" class=" sc-tab-link '. ( ($datatab == 1) ?  "current"  :  '') .' " data-tab="tab-'.$datatab.'">'.$top_term_name.'</li>';


            $second_level_terms[] = get_terms( array(
                    'taxonomy' => $top_term_tax, // you could also use $taxonomy as defined in the first lines
                    'child_of' => $top_term_id,
                    'parent' => $top_term_id, // disable this line to see more child elements (child-child-child-terms)
                    'hide_empty' => false,
            ) );    

            } // end of top level foreach   
            $html .= '</ul>';

            /*echo '<pre>';
                print_r($second_level_terms);
            echo '</pre>';*/

            if($second_level_terms) {   
                $contenttab = 0;    
                $html .= '<div class="sc-tab-content-wrapper">';    
                    foreach($second_level_terms as $row => $innerArray){
                        $contenttab++;
                        $html .= '<div id="tab-'.$contenttab.'" class="sc-tab-content '. ( ($contenttab == 1) ?  "current"  :  '') .' ">';
                            foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
                                    $second_term_name = $value->name;
                                    $second_level_term_id = $value->term_id;
                                    $html .= '<p>'.$value->name.'</p>';

                                    $third_level_terms[] = get_terms( array(
                                        'taxonomy' => $top_term_tax, // you could also use $taxonomy as defined in the first lines
                                        'parent' => $second_level_term_id,
                                        'child_of' =>  $second_level_term_id,
                                        'hide_empty' => false,
                                    ) );

                                    /** THIS BLOCK CODE IS WHAT I'M HAVING ISSUE WITH **/

                                    if($third_level_terms) {
                                        foreach ($third_level_terms as $row => $innerArray){
                                            foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
                                                $html .= '<p style="padding-left: 15px; font-size: 12px;">'. $value->name.'</p>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    } /** THIS BLOCK CODE IS WHAT I'M HAVING ISSUE WITH **/
                         }
                        $html .= '</div>';
                    }
                $html .= '</div>';
            } // end of if second leveL term        

            echo '<pre>';
                print_r($third_level_terms);
            echo '</pre>';

    return $html;
```

Current Result:

`Parent Category > Child Category > Inner Child Category(ALL INNER CHILD CATEGORIES SHOWS PER CHILD CATEGORY)`

Expected Result:

`Parent Category > Child Category > Inner Child Category` (Should display per Child Category)

I hope this was clear to understand! Please do tell me where I did wrong. I'm so confused on how to access the third level of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and solved my problem!

Had to comment out the code for the loop to work as intended!

```
$second_level_terms[] = get_terms( array(
                    'taxonomy' => $top_term_tax, 
                    'child_of' => $top_term_id,
                    //'parent' => $top_term_id, // This line of code was the problem! ugh!
                    'hide_empty' => false,
            ) );
```